# Why do udp and udp6 have different port behaviors?

Tags: linux, java, udp, network-protocols

I have two Linux servers. I run the same Java application on both of them. One of them runs as **udp** and the other as **udp6**. When I send a request to the **udp** application, it returns to me over a consistent port. But when I send a request to my **udp6** application, it returns to me via a random port.

Why does udp6 return over a random port?
Is it possible to change my udp6 application to udp?

Server 1 (udp):
[image: Server 1]

Server 2 (udp6):
[image: Server 2]

Thank you.

Comment: udp6 is just udp over ipv6 instead of ipv4. Nothing special. Nothing inherent which would make udp6 use random ports, i.e. there is likely a different handling for this somewhere inside your application instead. And yes, an application can be coded to use use udp6 and udp at the same time.

Comment: Where a UDP checksum is _optional_ in IPv4, it is _required_ in IPv6.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich;  as I said, the same application is running on both servers. Actually my goal is to listen to the port of the application with tcpdump. I am running the application on port 50001, on the first server I can see all incoming and outgoing messages. On the second server I can only see incoming messages, because outgoing messages are sent on a different port. I don't understand why the same application behaves like this on different servers. The operating systems of the servers; 
First server: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7
Second server: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6

Comment: @OmerFarukBalli: The OS does not matter, how this behaves depends on the application.

Comment: how and where are you running tcpdump?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IPv6 or networking. If an application on *your* host is communicating with another host using an unexpected port, it's your application.

Comment: I run tcpdump on my server. I open and check it with the Wireshark program. While the first server returns with the same port, the second server returns with a random port. @natxoasenjo

Comment: The same application is running on both servers. I could not understand the same application behaving in a different way. Could it be related to the ip route table? Could the ip route table interfere with my application? I am undecided. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: @OmerFarukBalli: There is absolutely nothing known about your application except that it is written in Java and behaves differently. Any question of type "could it be that ...." can only be answered with "maybe or maybe not".

Comment: the java engine is probably different on the two systems, so it's not the same running, and many other things. The application could behave differently itself. `strace` on the application would be more useful. But using `strace` on a java application is difficult because it's heavily multithreaded. Maybe `strace -e trace=%network`.  Don't put it in the question unless you know how to pinpoint what to put. Instead it has to be understood and checked along the source code. There can be only conjectures until something very concrete is provided. And then maybe that'd be for SO.

Comment: @OmerFarukBalli, I would like the command you use and a bit of the udp traffic, because I do not understand what you actually mean. The server always listen on the same port, be it ipv4 or ipv6, but the client can send traffic from any random high port which is free on its interface. So the client port number is not really important. That is why I would like to see a whole send/receive packet range in order to better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is UDP.

"udp6" is just a language or API convention for UDP over IPv6, in contrast to the traditional IPv4. Whether your application uses a fixed or an ephemeral port is defined by your call and possibly the API as well. A fixed port below a certain, system-specific value may require elevated privileges.